# Self-compiled vim not finding syntax.vim on Fedora 21

Tags: vim

I just built vim in a local directory so it is self contained.
It went OK, I can start vim/gvim etc...

But when I start vim I get the following message:

```
[statquant@localhost BuildFromSources]$ ./myOwnVim/usr/bin/vim
Error detected while processing /home/statquant/.vimrc:
line   85:
E484: Can't open file /usr/share/vim/syntax/syntax.vim
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

For some reason I think it does not know what `$VIM` is.

Indeed even after setting

```
$VIM=$HOME/BuildFromSources/myOwnVim/usr/share/vim
```

in `.bashrc` and sourcing it, it does not pick it up (doing `:echo` within vim gives `/usr/share/vim` which is the fall back)

What should I do to set it up correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running `./configure` you need include the argument `--prefix=path/to/install/location`. After compiling you then run `make install`, which will place all files in the desired location.
This will allow you to have a custom vim install.

In summary:

1. `./configure --prefix=path/to/install/location`.
2. `make`.
3. `make install`.

Comment: I use `--prefix` all the time and I have no need for post installation environment settings. Could you please try this option to see if it works?

Comment: It's not expected that you would need to use `sudo`.

Comment: Please confirm that you are following the exact steps I describe in the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the complete instructions

```
#install all packages
sudo yum install -y ruby ruby-devel \
    lua lua-devel luajit luajit-devel \
    ctags mercurial tcl-devel \
    python python-devel python3 python3-devel \
    perl perl-devel perl-ExtUtils-ParseXS \
    perl-ExtUtils-XSpp perl-ExtUtils-CBuilder \
    perl-ExtUtils-Embed
```

This step is needed to rectify an issue with how Fedora 20 installs XSubPP

```
#symlink xsubpp (perl) from /usr/bin to the perl dir
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/xsubpp /usr/share/perl5/ExtUtils/xsubpp
```

Sources are available via mercurial

```
#download the sources in $HOME/Sources
mkdir $HOME/Sources
cd $HOME/Sources
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/vim/
cd vim
```

The vim we build should have all features

```
#configure the install, vim will be located at $HOME/Build/vim 
mkdir $HOME/Build/vim
./configure --with-features=huge \
            --enable-fail-if-missing \
            --enable-luainterp=yes \
            --enable-mzschemeinterp \
            --enable-perlinterp \
            --enable-pythoninterp=yes \
            --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib64/python2.7/config \
            --enable-python3interp=yes \
            --enable-tclinterp=yes \
            --enable-rubyinterp=yes \
            --enable-cscope \
            --enable-multibyte \
            --enable-gui=gtk2 \
            --prefix=$HOME/Build/vim \
            --with-compiledby=YOU
```

Then the installation

```
#install 
make install
```

It should look like this

```
#check the install
[statquant@localhost vim]$ tree -L 3 $HOME/Build/vim/
home/statquant/Build/vim
├── bin
│   ├── eview -> vim
│   ├── evim -> vim
│   ├── ex -> vim
│   ├── gview -> vim
│   ├── gvim -> vim
│   ├── gvimdiff -> vim
│   ├── gvimtutor
│   ├── rgview -> vim
│   ├── rgvim -> vim
│   ├── rview -> vim
│   ├── rvim -> vim
│   ├── view -> vim
│   ├── vim
│   ├── vimdiff -> vim
│   ├── vimtutor
│   └── xxd
└── share
    ├── man
    │   ├── fr
    │   ├── fr.ISO8859-1
    │   ├── fr.UTF-8
    │   ├── it
    │   ├── it.ISO8859-1
    │   ├── it.UTF-8
    │   ├── ja
    │   ├── man1
    │   ├── pl
    │   ├── pl.ISO8859-2
    │   ├── pl.UTF-8
    │   ├── ru.KOI8-R
    │   └── ru.UTF-8
    └── vim
        └── vim74
```

And last:

```
#change ~/.bashrc so you can call vim/gvim...
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Build/vim/bin

#source your bashrc
source ~/.bashrc

#to uninstall
cd $HOME/Sources/vim
make uninstall
```

That's what you get:

```
[statquant@localhost vim]$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Apr 19 2015 16:16:44)
Included patches: 1-703
Compiled by statquant
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
+balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
+browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     +tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
+clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
+clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      +toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3/dyn     +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con_gui  +lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      +X11
+dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     +xim
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      -sniff           +xsmp_interact
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     +xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    +xpm
```